# mysql compare columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two different tables: one called XY and the other called XZ
In each table I have a column named "id" and I want to compare those columns and to see which one of the "id" values in table XY is also available in XZ and which isn't available

Comment: It's better to give a sample output for your requirement. please put an example.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-ways-to-sync-2-MySQL-databases-with-the-push-of-a-button-in-an-independent-cloud-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the id's that are in XY and not in XZ  (The inner query gives the id's present in both XY and XZ)

```
SELECT XY.`id` 
FROM XY
WHERE `id` NOT IN(
   SELECT XY.`id` 
   FROM XY
   JOIN XZ ON XY.`id`=XZ.`id`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is a simplle inner join

```
select * from table XY 
inner join XZ on (XY.id = XZ.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

id values on X.Y is available in X.Z,

```
SELECT XY.id FROM XY 
INNER JOIN XZ ON XY.id = XZ.id;
```

id values on X.Y is also NOT available in X.Z

```
SELECT XY.id FROM XY 
INNER JOIN XZ ON XY.id != XZ.id;
```